# jQuery IMG Slider - Phantom Margin

Tags: html, css, border, margin, padding

```
<div class="pictures">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="img1.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img2.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img3.jpg" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm building a jQuery IMG slider and the basic code breakdown is what you see above. I'm having a bunch of different issues, but one, in particular, is kind of baffling.  There seems to be a partial pixel space (1.5px, I believe) between each photo... not sure if it's a margin, padding, a border or something else. I have to animate the photos 331.5px up or down in order for them sit properly inside the container div. My general reset.css doesn't work. I have border, margin, margin-width and padding all set to 0 by default.

This is weird. Any ideas why it's happening? Or how I can eliminate it?

Link to actual page:   http://www.ficreates.com/_SiteDemos/PBL/projects.html

Comment: the one a the top of the images ?

Comment: it is most definitely due to your layout, if you zoom-in for instance it disappears check your element for hardcoded size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things going on here.

First thing is that `body {line-height: 1;}` is inherited by your `ul`.  Get rid of that or override it such as `ul {lineheight: 0;}` and the black spacing is gone.

Doing this does not align your animation though so you are going to have to fix your script.

One thing I noticed is that you are animating the position of the `img` tag instead of the container element such as the `ul`.  Curious why you are doing it this way.  Usually one would just do the += or -= on the container element.  You can set the `ul` to `display: block;` if needed.

Hope this helps.  Let me know if you have further questions.  Perhaps later I can get a full working example.

Comment: Oh man, I spent sooooo long trying to figure this out. You're awesome!

Also, I'm doing a lot of tweaks to the code right now, so it's going to some finagling to make it work, but you make a very valid point about simply animating the ul rather than each individual img.

I appreciate, not only your help in solving the problem, but the extra advice.